# flutter app not run on mac give me error while run on simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

while running flutter app give me this errors

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           32.8s
Finished with error: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting Xcode / Simulator and your IDE (i.e. VS Code).
It worked for me!.